# Intuition behind Variance formula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, intuition

Variance is given as:
$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2]$.

Is there an intuition behind this and can you find this formula starting from the second generating moment ?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We want to measure the expected “deviation” of a random variable from it's expected value.  What comes first in mind is the expected *difference*  between the r.v.  and it's expected value, that is $E\bigl(X-E(X)\bigr)$.  But this number is always zero. --

Next, as drhab pointed out, is the average *distance*, i.e., the absolute value of the difference, between the r.v. and it's expected value, that is $E\bigl(|X-E(X)|\bigr)$. Now that appears to be a “natural” measure of the deviation, but there is a big drawback: it's not everywhere differentiable, so we can't apply Analysis to it.

Now we're stuck; what to do know?  Well, let's follow an idea of a great mathematician, in our case Gauss.  He introduced in his early years the expected value of the *squared difference* between the r.v. and it's expected value, that is $E\bigl((X-E(X))^2\bigr)$, aka variance of $X$.  Its drawback: it isn't intuitive.

At the other hand, as  Stefanos wrote: “The moment of the most use is when k=2.”  That's right, but why is it the moment of most use?  The main reason for this is doubtlessly Chebyshev's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality
And this inequality is very intuitive.

Comment: Hi Michael. Today I was viewing [this](https://eeweb.ee.ucla.edu/video/ee210a_lec1_files/flash_index.htm) video where there is a nice intuitive interpretation of the variance (slide 10) and a quantification of that intuition through the Chebyshev's inequality in slides 15-17. I suggest you to improve your answer taking into consideration this source. By other hand, I think that after your first two paragraphs you can convince the reader that squaring the differences is a reasonable (and in that way intuitive) choice to overcome the drawbacks you pointed out in the first two approaches

Answer (score 3):

If I want to 'measure' how much random variable $X$ is *expected* to differ from its expected value than *intuitively* I think of things like $\mathbb E(|X-\mathbb E(X)|)$ or $\mathbb E(X-\mathbb E(X))^2$. Another possibility in the same line is the root of the variance, named deviation. Have a look at the anwer of Stefanos when it concerns second generating moment.

Answer (score 1):

The idea one can say, is that the variance is a measure of how the values of a random variables are spread in the space. So if you have a random variable that takes many values identical to the mean value and few values far away from the mean then that means that distribution is more focused in a smaller space, hence the variance is smaller.
In other words the variance of a random variable ($X$) measures the amount by which $X$ tends to deviate from the average value.

If you want to have a formula for the variance having the second generating moment: 
$$Var(X)=E[(X-E(X))^2]=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$$

In general we define  $\sigma_k=E[(X-\mu_k)^k]$ as the $k_{th}$ central moment of $X$. The moment of the most use is when $k=2$