# What is standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Is standard deviation defined to quantify the spread of the data from the mean? But average deviation can do the same.Then why is standard deviation defined, How is it better than average deviation?Other than the formula, what is the difference between them?

Comment: The average deviation is zero. If you mean the mean absolute deviation, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717339/why-is-variance-squared or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717339/why-is-variance-squared

Comment: @leonbloy: Heads up: you wrote the same link twice.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry. The second link should be https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for answering.I read the answers in the link but most of them were a bit advanced for me.But I understood a bit.Why isnt the introductory texts on statistics or the teachers in schools explaining these things?Is there any book on statistics that explains all of these things in the right order like 'why is it so' and 'why not'(for beginners, undergrads)?