# Why is variance squared rather than cubed (or any other exponent)?

Tags: statistics, variance

Variance is

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}$$

But why square the difference? Why not cube it, or any other exponent?

Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717339/why-is-variance-squared/717355).

Comment: If you cube it then some errors will cancel others due to negative signs and that is not good.

Comment: First of all, your formula is not the variance, but rather the *sample variance*. The variance of a random variable $X$ is defined as $$\mathbf{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2].$$ Now you may still ask what is the advantage of squaring the deviation $X-\mathbb{E}[X]$. My personal impression on this question is two-fold: (1) Variance is one of the two parameters that characterize the normal distribution. (2) Variance comes from covariance, which gives rise to the (degenerate) inner-product structure on the space of square-integrable random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use other exponents, but then it is not called variance anymore. See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), for example.

Variance comes up quite naturally in various contexts, and carries a lot of information about the distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Still, I am not convinced by this answer. 
The naming convention can be separate topics to discuss.
Here what is the issue if we take cubes or quad etc?