# How do you explain to a layman what a standard error is?

Tags: statistics

For example, if you were to regress $Y$ on $X$ and find that the standard error of the $X$ coefficient is $10$, what does the $10$ mean in layman's language?

Comment: What about "the quadratic mean of the error" ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700160/intuition-behind-variance-forumla/700231#700231

Comment: It also can be described as the "root-mean-square" deviation - that is the square root of the mean of the squares of the deviations of the values from the average. For a normal distribution, approximately 2/3 of the data points will lie within this distance from the average (actually, a little greater than 2/3). So it gives you an idea of how widely spread out your data is. The greater the std deviation is, the greater influence factors you are not accounting for are having on your data.